# sed string replace is giving some kind of warning?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I am using sed with grep command to replace a string. Old string is in 8 files at home location and I want to replace all of these with new string. I am using this:

```
#! /bin/bash

read oldstring
read newstring 

sed -i -e 's/'Soldstring'/'$newstring'/' grep "$oldstring" /home/*
```

Now this command works but I am getting an warning:

```
sed: can't read grep: No such file or directory
sed: can't read oldstring: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Soldstring` should be `$oldstring`?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the command does not, in fact, work. Perhaps you really want `grep` to give you a list of filenames to feed to `sed`, in which case you should have `sed ... $(grep -l ...)`. Also, `Soldstring != $oldstring`, and your `sed` program should look more like `"s/$oldstring/$newstring/" in case someone enters a string with a space in it...

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted

```
sed -i -e "s|Soldstring|$newstring|" $(grep -l "$oldstring" /home/*)
```

However that form is unsafe. Better use xargs:

```
grep -l "$oldstring" /home/* | xargs sed -i -e "s|Soldstring|$newstring|"
```

And another if possible is to store on arrays:

```
readarray -t files < <(exec grep -l "$oldstring" /home/*)
sed -i -e "s|Soldstring|$newstring|" "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing `grep`, you are giving it as a parameter to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

are you missing backticks?

```
sed -i -e 's/'Soldstring'/'$newstring'/' `grep "$oldstring" /home/*`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -i -e "s/$oldstring/$newstring/g" `grep -l "$oldstring" /home/*`
```

Comment: While this may answer the Question, a code-only answer is rarely as helpful as one that explains to the OP why it is a solution to their problem. Please consider adding some text that points out where the OP was going wrong or why this solution should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to clearly point out the various *typos* in your code:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 # ^
 # extra space here (not really an error I think -- but unusual)

 read oldstring
 read newstring 

 sed -i -e 's/'Soldstring'/'$newstring'/'    grep "$oldstring" /home/*
 #             ^                          ^                             ^
 #    `S` instead of `$` here             |                             |
 #                                       here         and             there
 #                                             missing backticks (`)
```

As a side note, I suggest *backticks* above, but, since you are using `bash`, the syntax `$(grep ....)` is probably better than the classic Bourne Shell syntax `` `grep ....` ``. Finally, as suggested by *konsolebox*, "command nesting" might be unsafe, for example, in this case, if some file names contain spaces.